# How to emulate a servlet path

Tags: servlets, path

I would like to emulate a servlet path like this.

```
/servlet/subservlet/subsubservlet
```

To do this what I have to do? Create three different servlet?

Answer (score 0):

**By adding a servlet Mapping you can do that.**

```
 `<servlet>`
```

`<servlet-name>ServletServlet</servlet-name>`

`<servlet-class>weblogic.servlet.ServletServlet</servlet-class>`

`</servlet>`

`<servlet-mapping>`

`<servlet-name>ServletServlet</servlet-name>`

`<url-pattern>/myservlet/*</url-pattern>`

`</servlet-mapping>`